# VSCode only shows 1 tab even with the tabs setting enabled

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

I did `right-click > Close All` , and ever since that I've only been able to keep 1 tab open. If I click on a different file, it closes the previous file. I have the setting `Workbench › Editor: Show Tabs` enabled, but it still doesn't let me open additional tabs. Only if I double click the file it opens it in a new tab, but I would like this to happen with a single click. I've tried restarting VSCode, but the problem persists.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. One click _previews_ the file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was able to open files (not preview) with a single click before I did `Close All`, though... There is a setting that you can set to open files with a single click, and it's set to that in my settings.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by disabling the setting `Workbench › Editor: Enable Preview`.